# Wowza: Seek certain part of video stream

Tags: video, streaming, rtmp, clip, wowza

I have Wowza installed and would like to know if it's possible to stream a certain part of a video, e.g. 0:30 to 0:45 (15 second clip), over RTMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- RTMP is a protocol for streaming, and Wowza supports it
- Seeking mechanisms are not streaming server specific, but protocol specific

So, what you want to do is seek into a video via RTMP.  The fact that videos are hosted on Wowza does not matter.  What is more of a question is ***"What player are you using?"***

Here are [some instructions](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/javascript-interaction/4370/javascript-seek-with-rtmp) for doing this with the JW Player, a very popular player.